# If else use in spinners

Tags: java, android, if-statement, spinner

I want to take the value in spinner and user press the ok Button and then start new activity from against the value of spinner. The string array is just like that. and I use two spinners value get and new activity start against the spinners

```
Spinner s, s1;
    Button ok;
    Object _globalString, _globalString2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner01);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
//
//    s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
//    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,array_spinner02);
//    s2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        s.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            //@Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        s1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                _globalString2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            // @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_ok) {
            if (_globalString.equals("Honda") || _globalString2.equals("Civic")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Civic.class));
            } else if (_globalString.equals("Toyota") || _globalString2.equals("Gli")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Toyota.class));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

here is the code this can error generate.  Sorry application has been stopped 
so i stuck on this code.

Comment: Add the crash logs.Have you added the activities in manifest?

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace from the crash? It will greatly assist people who want to help you.

Comment: You can not use setOnItemClickListener for spinner. Let change setOnItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

use **setOnItemSelectedListener** instead of **setOnItemClickListener**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Spinner s, s1;
    Button ok;
    Object _globalString, _globalString2;
    String[] array_spinner = {"Honda", "Toyota"};
    String[] array_spinner01 = {"Civic", "Gli"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);

        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array_spinner01);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter1);
//
//    s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner02);
//    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,array_spinner02);
//    s2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                _globalString = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                _globalString2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_ok) {
            if (_globalString.equals("Honda") || _globalString2.equals("Civic")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Civic.class));
            } else if (_globalString.equals("Toyota") || _globalString2.equals("Gli")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Toyota.class));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you also have to fix your declarations **Object _globalString, _globalString2;**

Comment: also offer to use **equalsIgnoreCase** instead of **equals**

Comment: i fix this deceleration before your message Object _globalString to String __globalString so same problem and equalsIgnoreCase is not worked